# How to pass three parameter in url for retrieving data using json parser in android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I have two spinner and date picker in the first class in the 1st spinner I have selected location the related stock point flow on the 2nd spinner and selected date, and three string object sent to next class using put string,get string and added to url item,item1,date. and run the application select location, stockpoint, date then press get table button it will force close. I debug it the object is sent and add successfully when cursor come to JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); it will close . when I comment url and replace predefined url it will run.. I cant identify the problem

```
public void torun() {

    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String items=b.getString("item");
    String items1=b.getString("item1");
    String dates=b.getString("date");

   // String url0 = "http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/?Location=ArihantWanarpet&GROUP=ArihantShowroom&asondate=2013-2-24";


    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?Location="+items+"&GROUP="+items1+"&asondate="+dates;


    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     // getting JSON string from URL

    try {
        JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONArray list = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_JSONDataResult);


        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String GRPCODE = c.getString(TAG_GRPCODE);
            String GRPNAME = c.getString(TAG_GRPNAME);
            String QTY = c.getString(TAG_QNT);
            String BUDGET = c.getString(TAG_BUDGET);
            String STOCK = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
            String DIFF = c.getString(TAG_DIFF);
            String DIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_DIFF_P);
            String EQTY = c.getString(TAG_EQTY);
            String EQTY_P = c.getString(TAG_EQTY_P);
            String EBUDGET = c.getString(TAG_EBUDGET);
            String ESTK = c.getString(TAG_ESTK);
            String ESTK_P = c.getString(TAG_ESTK_P);
            String EDIFF = c.getString(TAG_EDIFF);
            String EDIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_EDIFF_P);
            String DQTY = c.getString(TAG_DQTY);
            String DQTY_P = c.getString(TAG_DQTY_P);
            String DBUDGET = c.getString(TAG_DBUDGET);
            String DSTK = c.getString(TAG_DSTK);
            String DSTK_P = c.getString(TAG_DSTK_P);
            String DDIFF = c.getString(TAG_DDIFF);
            String DDIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_DDIFF_P);
            String PQTY = c.getString(TAG_PQTY);
            String PQTY_P = c.getString(TAG_PQTY_P);
            String PBUDGET = c.getString(TAG_PBUDGET);
            String PSTK = c.getString(TAG_PSTK);
            String PSTK_P = c.getString(TAG_PSTK_P);
            String PDIFF = c.getString(TAG_PDIFF);
            String PDIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_PDIFF_P);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_GRPCODE, GRPCODE);
            map.put(TAG_GRPNAME, GRPNAME);
            map.put(TAG_QNT, QTY);
            map.put(TAG_BUDGET, BUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_STOCK, STOCK);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF, DIFF);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF_P, DIFF_P);
            map.put(TAG_EQTY, EQTY);
            map.put(TAG_EQTY_P, EQTY_P);
            map.put(TAG_EBUDGET, EBUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_ESTK, ESTK);
            map.put(TAG_ESTK_P, ESTK_P);
            map.put(TAG_EDIFF, EDIFF);
            map.put(TAG_EDIFF_P, EDIFF_P);
            map.put(TAG_DQTY, DQTY);
            map.put(TAG_DQTY_P, DQTY_P);
            map.put(TAG_DBUDGET, DBUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_DSTK, DSTK);
            map.put(TAG_DSTK_P, DSTK_P);
            map.put(TAG_DDIFF, DDIFF);
            map.put(TAG_DDIFF_P, DDIFF_P);
            map.put(TAG_PQTY, PQTY);
            map.put(TAG_PQTY_P, PQTY_P);
            map.put(TAG_PBUDGET, PBUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_PSTK, PSTK);
            map.put(TAG_PSTK_P, PSTK_P);
            map.put(TAG_PDIFF, PDIFF);
            map.put(TAG_PDIFF_P, PDIFF_P);
            //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */


     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_GRPCODE, TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, TAG_EQTY, TAG_EQTY_P, TAG_EBUDGET, TAG_ESTK,
                    TAG_ESTK_P, TAG_EDIFF, TAG_EDIFF_P, TAG_DQTY, TAG_DQTY_P, TAG_DBUDGET, TAG_DSTK, TAG_DSTK_P, TAG_DDIFF, TAG_DDIFF_P, TAG_PQTY,
                    TAG_PQTY_P, TAG_PBUDGET, TAG_PSTK, TAG_PSTK_P, TAG_PDIFF, TAG_PDIFF_P },
            new int[] {
                    R.id.l1, R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7, R.id.l8, R.id.l9, R.id.l10, R.id.l11, R.id.l12, R.id.l13, R.id.l14,
                    R.id.l15, R.id.l16, R.id.l17, R.id.l18, R.id.l19, R.id.l20, R.id.l21, R.id.l22, R.id.l23, R.id.l24, R.id.l25, R.id.l26, R.id.l27, R.id.l28, });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem

}
```

> JSONParser class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

> logcat

```
07-03 07:25:21.177      632-632/com.android.exchange           E/StrictMode: null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d33ec0 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

> latest logcat error

```
07-03 07:47:04.487    1877-1877/com.androidhive.innovate       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.innovate/com.androidhive.innovate.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 49: http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=ArihantWanarpet&GROUP=ArihantShowroom&asondate=2013-7-3
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 49: http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=ArihantWanarpet&GROUP=ArihantShowroom&asondate=2013-7-3
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
    at com.androidhive.innovate.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:36)
    at com.androidhive.innovate.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.torun(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:105)
    at com.androidhive.innovate.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your json parser class..

Comment: are you use Simpledate format for date?

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal ok i added, i use date picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok....So finally you have to change your string of date to SimpleDateformat and then add that string to URL:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(dates);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);
```

and then add to:

```
    String myUrl;
    myUrl = String.format("http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?   Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s",items,items1,finalDate );
```

Comment: Could you please stop creating multiple answers for a question? If the OP added new information, you should edit your answer and not create a new one! This is not a forum, it is a Q&A ...

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal still problem here... same error please tell me how to fix it

Comment: @WarrenFaith sorry i cant understand what is OP?

Comment: OP == Original Poster. In this case it means that you are the OP.